# How to change GAE instance class without redeploying app

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there any way, we can update the instance class from `appengine-web.xml`, without redeploying the app.
I would like to change my app instance from `F1` to `F4_1G`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to change the instance class is currently by means of your configuration file (appengine-web.xml, app.yaml). In order to apply your changes, you have to redeploy the app.

Earlier it was also possible to change instance class in App Engine Console, however, since the introduction of modules and the new Google Cloud Console, no such an option is available.